# Could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory problem

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I closed the opened eclipse forcibly from task manager and after that i'm recieving the following error in the JSF project i was working at that time.

Plz tell me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

**Error:-**could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Following is the **stack trace.**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Oct 21, 2003 3:41:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Faces Servlet
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you paste your web.xml? What servlet container are you deploying? Make sure your web.xml has `Faces Servlet` class defined. Are you packaging JSF with your app for any reason?

Comment: @CoolBeans:I've added web.xml, kindly check again. My project is in development stage, i'm usiing Tomcat. Project is actually jsf based.

Comment: The `web.xml` snippet looks good. Let us know what happens after what awesome @BalusC recommended. Since it has worked before perhaps a clean restart might fix it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception: could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259145/exception-could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it has worked before you killed Eclipse/Tomcat by taskmanager? Maybe the deploy or work folder of Tomcat is actually dirty while Eclipse still thinks that it is clean. Rightclick Tomcat in Eclipse (first shutdown Tomcat if not done yet) and choose *Clean* and then *Publish* and then start it.

Comment: @CoolBeans and BalusC:Thanks v v v v much.