# Dynamic Web Project with Seam Faces

Tags: jsf, seam

I tried to start a new dynamic Web Project with Seam-Faces(Eclipse). I created a new JSF-Facility and addeed all the jar-Files from the official Seam-Faces homepage. When i try to create a dynamic web project eclipse says that the following File ist not found:

javax.faces.FactoryFinder

What i am doing wrong ? Is ist possible to use Seam-Faces without the Seam-Framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a Seam Framework anymore. Seam 3 is a bunch of reusable CDI extensions that you could use. The best way to start with Seam3 modules is to use maven for library management. More info about how to configure seam-faces dependencies can be found [here](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule). 
For the exception you're facing make sure there are no jsf jars in WEB-INF\lib in case you're using a Java EE server like JBoss AS or Glassfish. For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259145/exception-could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory).

Comment: The same as Struts - gone in the past.