# Getting error "Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory"

Tags: java, jsf, weblogic, icefaces

I am getting the subject error ,when I am trying to deploy my application on weblogic server . I tried with the answers provided to other similar questions,but it did not solve my error .

Please let me know what I am doing wrong .

my **web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>FedEx Location Services</display-name>
    <description>
    </description>

    <!-- Facelets composite component definitions. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/includes/components/comp.taglib.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.connectionTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>1800000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.responseBufferSize</param-name>
        <param-value>500000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
      <param-value>500000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.compressResources</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.theme</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/BOContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <listener>
         <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <!-- file upload Servlet -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableMissingResourceLibraryDetection
        </param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.connectionLostRedirectURI</param-name>
        <param-value>'logout.jsp?requestFrom=connectionLost'</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI</param-name>
        <param-value>'logout.jsp?requestFrom=SessionExpired'</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.externalizeJavaScript</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.icefaces.fastBusyIndicator</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fedex.itrigger.common.DownloadServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Startup Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.fedex.itrigger.common.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/download/DownloadServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xml</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
            <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

my **weblogic-application.xml**

```
<prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
    <prefer-application-resources>
        <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
        <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.FacesConfigResourceProvider</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
</weblogic-application>
```

**console error**

```
WARNING: ICEpush library missing. Push notification disabled.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Critical error during deployment:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:591)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:248)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:208)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:890)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar([Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLInputSource;)V
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:591)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.initStatics(DbfFactory.java:248)
        at com.sun.faces.config.DbfFactory.<clinit>(DbfFactory.java:208)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.<init>(ConfigManager.java:890)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.>
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "Faces Servlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/imktApp/iTrigger".
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1008)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:302)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Error> <javax.faces> <BEA-000000> <Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.>
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1008)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343)
        at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:131)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:328)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:662)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 5, 2016 10:37:45 AM GMT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "iTrigger".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1008)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:343)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:302)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:337)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:288)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: So e.g. this wasn't helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5259145 (that's the top one in "Related" list in right hand side). The answer says this can be caused by classpath pollution. You have nowhere in the current question explicitly excluded it being the cause.

Comment: I checked for first point .1. Get rid of jsf-api and jsf-impl JARs in your WAR (i.e. they should not end up in /WEB-INF/lib after build/deploy.